# How do I make Beautiful Soup return every table from an shtml page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to webscraping with python, and am looking to import all of the tables on [team pages](http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/ARI/2016.shtml) on baseball-reference.com using [open source code from github](https://github.com/andrewblim/br-scraper).  The issue that I'm running into is that the scraper will pick up the team pitching and the team batting tables, but not any of the others.  I've looked in the html on the webpage and saw that the fielding table is hardcoded, so there shouldn't be a problem with it not existing in the code.  I changed the brscraper.py code a little bit to error check, and saw that the only tables in the dictionary are team-batting and team-pitching.  I've also tried taking out all of the conditionals, and importing the tables with no if-statements, but nothing changed.  I'm curious if anybody knows a reason why Beautiful Soup wouldn't find all of the tables immediately.

Here is the code that I'm using for the webscraping, which finds tables/headers and then zips them together.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def removeExtraCharacters(s):
    if s.endswith('*'):
        s = s[0:-1]
    if s.endswith('#'):
        s = s[0:-1]
    return s

class BRScraper:

    def __init__(self, server_url="http://www.baseball-reference.com/"):
        self.server_url = server_url

    def parse_tables(self, resource, table_ids=None, verbose=False):
        """
        Given a resource on the baseball-reference server (should consist of 
        the url after the hostname and slash), returns a dictionary keyed on 
        table id containing arrays of data dictionaries keyed on the header 
        columns. table_ids is a string or array of strings that can     optionally 
        be used to filter out which stats tables to return. 
        """

        def is_parseable_table(tag):
            if not tag.has_attr("class"): return False
            return tag.name == "table" and "stats_table" in tag["class"] and     "sortable" in tag["class"]

        def is_parseable_row(tag):
            if not tag.name == "tr": return False
            if not tag.has_attr("class"): return True  # permissive
            return "league_average_table" not in tag["class"] and     "stat_total" not in tag["class"]

        if isinstance(table_ids, str): table_ids = [table_ids]

        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(self.server_url + resource),     "lxml")
        tables = soup.find_all("table")
        data = {}

        # Read through each table, read headers as dictionary keys
        for table in tables:

            if table_ids != None and table["id"] not in table_ids: continue
            if verbose: print "Processing table " + table["id"]
            data[table["id"]] = []

            headers = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
            header_names = []
            for header in headers:
                if header.string == None: 
                    base_header_name = ""
                else: base_header_name = header.string.strip()
                if base_header_name in header_names:
                    i = 1
                    header_name = base_header_name + "_" + str(i)
                    while header_name in header_names:
                        i += 1
                        header_name = base_header_name + "_" + str(i)
                    if verbose: 
                        if base_header_name == "":
                            print "Empty header relabeled as %s" %     header_name
                        else:
                            print "Header %s relabeled as %s" %     (base_header_name, header_name)
                else:
                    header_name = base_header_name
                header_names.append(header_name)
            header_names.pop(0) 
            rows = table.find("tbody").find_all(is_parseable_row)
            for row in rows:
                entries = row.find_all("td")
                entry_data = []
                for entry in entries:
                    # if entry.string == None:
                    #     entry_data.append("")
                    # else:
                       entry_data.append(removeExtraCharacters(entry.text.strip()))
            if len(entry_data) > 0:
                data[table["id"]].append(dict(zip(header_names, entry_data)))

    return data
```

And here is my implementation:

```
import brscraper

def encodeAscii(data_table):
    for i in range(len(data_table)):
        for j in range(len(data_table[0])):
            if data_table[i][j] is not None:
                data_table[i][j] = data_table[i][j].encode("ascii")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = brscraper.BRScraper()

    resources = [["teams/ARI/2016.shtml", "teams/ATL/2016.shtml", 
        "teams/BAL/2016.shtml", "teams/BOS/2016.shtml",     "teams/CHC/2016.shtml",
        "teams/CHW/2016.shtml", "teams/CIN/2016.shtml",     "teams/CLE/2016.shtml",
        "teams/COL/2016.shtml", "teams/DET/2016.shtml", "teams/HOU/2016.shtml",
        "teams/KCR/2016.shtml", "teams/LAA/2016.shtml",     "teams/LAD/2016.shtml",
        "teams/MIA/2016.shtml", "teams/MIL/2016.shtml",     "teams/MIN/2016.shtml",
        "teams/NYM/2016.shtml", "teams/NYY/2016.shtml",     "teams/OAK/2016.shtml", 
        "teams/PHI/2016.shtml", "teams/PIT/2016.shtml",     "teams/SDP/2016.shtml", 
        "teams/SFG/2016.shtml", "teams/SEA/2016.shtml",     "teams/STL/2016.shtml",
        "teams/TBR/2016.shtml", "teams/TEX/2016.shtml",     "teams/TOR/2016.shtml", 
        "teams/WSN/2016.shtml"]]

    teams ={'ARI': 'Arizona Diamondbacks', 'ATL': 'Atlanta Braves', 
            'BOS': 'Boston Red Sox', 'CHC': 'Chicago Cubs', 
            'CHW': 'Chicago White Sox', 'CIN': 'Cincinnati Reds',
            'CLE': 'Cleveland Indians', 'COL': 'Colorado Rockies',
            'DET': 'Detroid Tigers', 'HOU': 'Houston Astros', 
            'KCR': 'Kansas City Royals', 'LAA': 'Los Angeles Angels of     Anaheim',
            'LAD': 'Los Angeles Dodgers', 'MIA': 'Miami Marlins',
            'MIL': 'Milwaukee Brewers', 'MIN': 'Minnesota Twins',
            'NYM': 'New York Mets', 'NYY': 'New York Yankees',
            'OAK': 'Oakland Athletics', 'PHI': 'Philadelphia Phillies', 
            'PIT': 'Pittsbugh Pirates', 'SDP': 'San Diego Padres',
                'SFG': 'San Francisco Giants', 'SEA': 'Seattle Mariners',
            'STL': 'St. Louis Cardinals', 'TBR': 'Tampa Bay Rays',
            'TEX': 'Texas Rangers', 'TOR': 'Toronto Blue Jays', 
            'WSN': 'Washington Nationals', 'BAL': 'Baltimore Orioles'}

    # all_orders contains information about the order of the data
    # all_orders is what the headers of our tables should be

    # all_data is the data itself
    # all_data and all_orders will both have the same keys
    # So all_data['batting'] = the 2D array of batting data
    #    all_orders['batting'] = the headers for each column of batting data

    all_data = {}
    all_orders = {}

    team_batting_list = ["name", "team_name", "at_bats", "hits", "homeruns",
                         "runs_batted_in", "stolen_bases"]

    team_pitching_list = ["name", "team_name", "wins", "losses", "saves",
                          "innings_pitched", "earned_run_average",     "strikeouts"]

    team_fielding_list = ["name", "team_name", "position", "games_played", 
                          "put_outs", "assists", "errors",     "fielding_percentage"]

    team_batting = []
    team_pitching = []
    team_fielding = []

    for team_name in resources[0]:
        print team_name
        data = scraper.parse_tables(team_name)

        print data.keys()

        ###########
        # BATTING #
        ###########

        if "team_batting" in data.keys():
            for row in data["team_batting"]:
                team_batting.append([])
                team_batting[-1].append(row["Name"])
                team_batting[-1].append(teams[team_name[6:9]])
                team_batting[-1].append(row["AB"])
                team_batting[-1].append(row["H"])
                team_batting[-1].append(row["HR"])
                team_batting[-1].append(row["RBI"])
                team_batting[-1].append(row["SB"])

        ############
        # PITCHING #
        ############

        if "team_pitching" in data.keys():
            for row in data["team_pitching"]:
                team_pitching.append([])
                team_pitching[-1].append(row["Name"])
                team_pitching[-1].append(teams[team_name[6:9]])
                team_pitching[-1].append(row["W"])
                team_pitching[-1].append(row["L"])
                team_pitching[-1].append(row["SV"])
                team_pitching[-1].append(row["ERA"])
                team_pitching[-1].append(row["SO"])

        ############
        # FIELDING #
        ############

        if "team_fielding" in data.keys():
            for row in data["team_fielding"]:
                team_fielding.append([])
                team_fielding[-1].append(row["Name"])
                team_fielding[-1].append(teams[team_name[6:9]])
                team_fielding[-1].append(row["Pos"])
                team_fielding[-1].append(row["G"])
                team_fielding[-1].append(row["PO"])
                team_fielding[-1].append(row["A"])
                team_fielding[-1].append(row["E"])
                team_fielding[-1].append(row["Fld%"])



    encodeAscii(team_batting)
    encodeAscii(team_pitching)
    encodeAscii(team_fielding)

    all_data['pitching'] = team_pitching
    all_orders['pitching'] = team_pitching_list

    all_data['batting'] = team_batting
    all_orders['batting'] = team_batting_list

    all_data['fielding'] = team_fielding
    all_orders['fielding'] = team_fielding_list

    print all_data['fielding']
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just as links to github.

Comment: Done! Sorry about not having done that, I am working in Vim in Windows, which doesn't have great features for copying from the console to other text boxes (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue, which has been addressed in other posts on stackoverflow, is that baseball-reference.com comments out significant parts of their html source code. As a person who hasn't studied html much, I am still a little confused on how those commented out tables nonetheless appear on the webpage. Either way, that's the crux of it.

Here's an example of a commented block for the all_standard_fielding table from the source code of the baseball-reference link that I posted above:

```
</div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--
<div class="table_outer_container">
      <div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_standard_fielding">
  <table class="sortable stats_table" id="standard_fielding" data-cols-to-freeze=1><caption>Team Fielding--Totals</caption>
   <colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
   <thead>      
      <tr>
 .
 .
 . and so on.
```

The entire table is commented out, so you need to remove those comments with regex commands before trying to import the data from the html source.

Answer (score 0):

This will output the tables as lists of lists, you can format however you want, also the headers aren't included in this table afaik:

`r = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/ARI/2016.shtml')`

`raw_data = [[cell.text for cell in row('td')] for row in BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')('tr')]`

```
>>> [[],
 [u'C',
  u'Welington Castillo',
  u'29',
  u'113',
  u'457',
  u'416',
  u'41',
  u'110',
  u'24',
  u'0',
  u'14',
  u'68',
  u'2',
  u'0',
  u'33',
  u'121',
  u'.264',
  u'.322',
  u'.423',
  u'.745',
  u'93',
  u'176',
  u'5',
  u'4',
  u'0',
  u'4',
  u'3'],
...]
```

Comment: Right, he zips the headers with the tables.  What I'm saying is that it doesn't find all of the tables on the page, only returning two for each team.  There should be 5 tables returned as I understand it...